# Python Why // gives different (absolute) value when applied on negative numbers versus positive

Tags: python

Sorry if the question is too trivial, what's the difference:

Code

```
print(14//3)  = 4 
print(-14//3) =-5
```

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Comment: `//` is floor operator so round towards negative/lower

Comment: This may be trivial, but I have to admit, I expected this to behave like `int(-14 / 3)`, i.e. round towards zero. Learned something new.

Answer (score 5):

The `//` is floor division in Python therefore the difference:

```
 14//3 = floor( 4.6666) =  4
-14//3 = floor(-4.6666) = -5
```

As the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html) state:

> The / (division) and // (floor division) operators yield the quotient of their arguments. The numeric arguments are first converted to a common type. Division of integers yields a float, while floor division of integers results in an integer; the result is that of mathematical division with the ‘floor’ function applied to the result. Division by zero raises the ZeroDivisionError exception.